# What happened to Chat?

Tags: discussion, design

I just noticed that he "chat" button disappeared and was replaced by "blog". Does that mean no more chat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/eeeek-where-did-the-chat-top-navigation-link-go/):

> It has been replaced for 24 hours by the blog link.
>
> When the blog is no longer "new" it will return.

and

> You can also find chat links, at least on any meta, on every question page in the sidebar.

I happen to agree with the commenter who said:

> Replacing a completely unrelated link temporarily because something is new is weird.

Anyway, the bottom line is that [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/jewish-life-and-learning) is still open.